# How to make certain lines in a listbox uneditable

Tags: vb.net

I have a edit button in my project which allows me to edit lines in my listbox, but there are certain lines I don't want to be editable, how can I make that possible.

I want to make line 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59, 64, 69, 74, 79, 84, 89, 94, 99 un-editable.

I want the applicationdate line to be un-editable, is there a way I can just make that line of code un-editable.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the [`SelectedIndexChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx). This event is raised each time that the item selection in the `ListBox` control changes.

Inside the event handler method for this event, check the index of the currently selected item. If it's one that you want to allow editing for, enable the Edit button. Otherwise, disable the Edit button.

For example:

```
Private Sub myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles myListBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Only allow editing of items with an odd-numbered index.
    ' (This isn't very useful, just a demonstration. You can use any criteria you
    '  want to determine whether editing should be allowed for the current item.)
    btnEdit.Enabled = myListBox.SelectedIndex Mod 2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Cody Gray, that helps me a bit, now I just have to work out how to get it to work on the certain lines that I want.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles myListBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Only allow editing of items with an odd-numbered index.
    ' (This isn't very useful, just a demonstration. You can use any criteria you
    '  want to determine whether editing should be allowed for the current item.)
    Dim unedit() as integer={4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59, 64, 69, 74, 79, 84, 89, 94, 99}
    dim i as integer
    for i = 0 unedit.count-1
    if myListBox.SelectedIndex=unedit(i) then
       btnEdit.Enabled = false
       exit for
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: With this code lines 1,5,9 are uneditable, it appears every 4th line becomes uneditable.

Comment: sorry, i screwed up the code. please check again. updating the answer